# how to appear Chatter posts for approval requests in lightning

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed, approval-process

I have created an approval process that allows users to approve the records from chatter.

Before Designing an approval process, I have enabled feed tracking for the object where I have designed the approval process. I have also Enable Allow Approvals in Chatter  by using the following steps

*Select Setup -> Customize -> Chatter -> Settings -> Edit -> Enable Allow Approvals*

In Classic I can see the approval request in Home/ chatter Page.

[image]

but as soon as I switched to Lightning Experience, I can not see the same post neither in Home nor in Chatter Tab.

From the below link Salesforce has mentioned that **Chatter posts for approval requests only appear in Salesforce Classic. To respond to approval requests in Lightning Experience, users go to the Approval Requests tab.**

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_post_templates_considerations.htm&type=5

I want to know is there a way(Customization?) where Approval Process chatter shown in lightning?

Comment: you need to raise the ticket with salesforce for enable the button in lightning